# Python property and Python property setters type modified

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am a python beginner and I am stuck in @property and @property. setter decorator.
I want to add some data to a dictionary named __content with the use of a setter.
This is my try, but when I run this script, only the last element is added to the dictionary!
So what am I missing here!

```
class Something:
    def __init__(self,elem):
        self.__content={}

        self.__content.update(elem)
        print type(self.__content)

    @property
    def content(self):
        return self.__content

    @content.setter
    def content(self,elem):
        self.__content.update(elem)
```

And

```
from transpose import Something
c=Something(dict(one=4))
print c.content
c.content=dict(two=6)
print c.content
```

The result

```
/usr/bin/python /home/radouani/PycharmProjects/demoPython/test.py
<type 'dict'>
{'one': 4}
<type 'dict'>
{'two': 6}
 Process finished with exit code 0
```

Another problem : I don't understand why python change the type of __content when I try to affect a tuple or integer with the use of the setter?

Cordially

Comment: If you're using Python2, you'll need to inherit from `object` IE `class Something(object)` -- In Python3 this is done for you automatically.

Comment: Thaks a lot it's works :) But what's the problem? Why inheritance is not explicity?

Comment: In Python3, this will happen for you -- All classes in Python3 are "New Style" classes. "New Style" classes were back-ported to Python2 -- but because it would otherwise change functionality for "old style" classes, you have to 'opt-in' to using New Style classes in Python2. In Python3, it's still preferred, but not required, that you do this inheritance explicitly for backwards compatibility. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I wasn't even aware there were new vs. old classes ! Thanks a lot sytech :) if you have please a good reference to learn the pythonic way i will be grateful

Comment: [Raymond Hettinger Python's Class Development Toolkit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HTLu2DFOdTg) This would be invaluable in learning the Pythonic way of developing classes. Raymond H is also an excellent authority for all Python topics. Read/watch his stuff whenever you can.

Comment: You are a lifesaver, thank you for all your effort!

Comment: @AdoRiadh: You should accept the answer which you think is the best answer for your question, as a reference for others looking for the same issue in future. Also it is the way to thank to people who helped you with their time and effort in the form of reputation (via upvote and accepting answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Properties don't work on old style classes. You have to inherit from object to create a new style class:

```
class Something(object):
    ...
```

From [`property` doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property):

> `class property([fget[, fset[, fdel[, doc]]]])`
>
> Return a property attribute for [new-style class](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-new-style-class)es (classes that derive from object).

Comment: BTW, note that my answer is specific to Python 2. In Python 3, every class is a new style class.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned previously, properties don't work on "old style" classes. You have to inherit from `object` to create a new style class in Python 2.x for properties to work.

```
class Something(object):
    #stuff
```

In Python 3.x, this will happen for you -- All classes in Python3 are "New Style" classes. "New Style" classes are also implemented in Python2, but because it would otherwise change functionality for "old style" classes, you have to 'opt-in' to using New Style classes in Python2 by inheriting from `object`.

Even though this happens implicitly and automatically in Python3, it's still preferred, but not required, that you do this inheritance from `object` explicitly for backwards compatibility.

A great resources for  developing classes: [Raymond Hettinger - Python's Class Development Toolkit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HTLu2DFOdTg)